# Using "key to" vs "keys to" for a single key

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Why is it considered acceptable to say "keys to the house" even when there is only one singular key?

Comment: I've never known new buyers (house or car) be given just one key, and would say that that is most unusual. And if the expression is meaningful in 99.9% of cases, it will be idiomatic enough for the very rare exceptional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an interesting [post on Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-English-is-it-better-to-say-car-keys-or-car-key) I found about "car key or car keys".

Essentially the two explanations there could explain the phenomenon in the context of house as well:

1. All one's keys are typically on one keychain, so the reference is rather to the whole keychain of *keys* on which you can find the singular house (or car) *key*.
2. Historically for cars, you needed 2 keys: one to open it and the other to start it and so the expression stuck. I would say that similarly with houses, there is generally more than one key (perhaps for other rooms, or sometimes multiple locks on the front door) and so as a result the expression also stuck.

There are other great examples in that Quora discussion which are highly pertinent.